# jQuery UI-animated text box hops into the container div only after toggle effect is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a container div, a one line-high div at the very top and a jQuery-hidden text box inside. There is a visible button on that bar. Clicking it should make the hidden text box slide into view, with the entire animation taking place on that thin header bar.

Instead, it animates outside the bar and jumps into the bar once the animation is complete.

Current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userNameInput').hide();
    $('#userNameInputButton').click(function() {
        $('#userNameInput').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8N2p/) and you'll understand. I'm new to jQuery. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the `css`

```
#userNameInputButton {
    float: left;
}

#userNameInput {
    width: 140px;
}
```

Updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N8N2p/4/)

Comment: If the provided answer is correct, please mark as correct. So it may help others while searching. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution still leaves the input box shifting up and down after the animation, it just no longer wraps to the next line.

Comment: @Siva.G IMHO, Your solution is a hack for the ``block formatting context``. It is not wise to hack it with ``floats``, if I may say so.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/N8N2p/2/).

CSS:

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    width: 140px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
}
```

Why it is happening?

If you look in the devtool, while animating, the `textbox` is wrapped by a `div` with `class .ui-effects-wrapper`. The on `animation complete` the `textbox` is taken out of this wrapper. Since `div` is a `block` element by default, you notice the the `jump` as `block elements` are stacked `horizontally` and not `vertically`

Comment: why the height changes before and after the animation

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle posted in the answer? I haven't seen any height changing.

Comment: s i checked the fiddle. When i click the button the toogle(input box) starts with someheight and at the end of the effect there is slight change in height. why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Css with

```
#userNameInput {
    padding: 0;
    width: 140px;
    float :left;
}
```

Comment: float: left; has to be set for userNameInputButton . if u set float left for userNameInput without setting float left for userNameInputButton  then while toggle input box appears before button